# Create function in dynamic sql PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to create a function or execute anonymous block inside dynamic SQL in PostgreSQL? 
I'm looking for something like this:

```
Create or replace FUNCTION fff(p1 int)
LANGUAGE  plpgsql
  AS $$
  DECLARE
   v_Qry  VARCHAR(4000);
  BEGIN
    v_Qry := '
    Create or replace FUNCTION fff_DYNAMIC_SQL()
    LANGUAGE  plpgsql
    AS $$
    DECLARE
    v1  INTEGER;
    begin
     v1 := ' || p1 || ';
     RETURN;
    END; $$;';
   EXECUTE v_Qry;
   RETURN;
END; $$;
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What happened when you tried?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I get the error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
LINE 11:   DECLARE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three levels of nested string in your code. The best way to deal with that, is to use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) for **all** of them. When creating dynamic SQL it's also better to use `format()` instead of string concatenation. Then you only need a single string with placeholders which makes the code a lot easier to read.

To nest multiple dollar quoted strings use a different delimiter each time:

```
Create or replace FUNCTION fff(p1 int)
  returns void
  LANGUAGE  plpgsql
AS
$$ --<< outer level quote
DECLARE
 v_Qry  VARCHAR(4000);
BEGIN
  v_Qry := format(
$string$ --<< quote for the string constant passed to the format function
    Create or replace FUNCTION fff_DYNAMIC_SQL()
       returns void
       LANGUAGE  plpgsql
    AS 
    $f1$ --<< quoting inside the actual function body
    DECLARE
      v1  INTEGER;
    begin
      v1 := %s;
      RETURN;
    END; 
    $f1$
$string$, p1);
  EXECUTE v_Qry;
  RETURN;
END; 
$$;
```

You also forgot to declare the returned data type. If the function does not return anything, you need to use `returns void`.

Comment: You're a lifesaver you know that @a_horse_with_no_name ?